# Set start URL for Visual Studio 2022 MVC project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Where can we set the URL that a MVC project starts at in Visual Studio 2022? This is the URL that will be loaded in the browser when we select `Start without Debugging`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to `Debug` -> `<YourProjectName> Debug Properties`
- A new dialog will open
- Scroll down to `Url`
- Enter the URL you want.

Note that the URL should already exists in our hosts file. (Assuming we are using this for local testing)

The URL should have a port taken from the `App URL` field. E.g. if your `App URL` field is
`https://localhost:7172;http://localhost:5172` and you want your browser to start at `https://test.example.com` when you run the project, then enter `https://test.example.com:7172` in the `Url` field.